# React-bootstrap modal displays an unexpected white background

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display a modal when cliking on a button using react-bootstrap, copy pasted the code from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/, but when I open the modal it displays an unexpected white background. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLGRe.png) of the issue  and here is another [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2ezp.png) of the expected behavior.

Here is my code :

```
function PartnershipCardList({partnerships}) {
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
return(
    <>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
            Launch demo modal
        </Button>

        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                    Close
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                    Save Changes
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    </>
)
```

}
export default PartnershipCardList

If you could help me in any way that would be really kind, have a good day

Comment: Are you using `Material UI` and `React-Bootstrap` together ??

Comment: just find backdrop selector and change color to transparent.

Comment: @Sayog I was using MaterializeCSS, removed it and now it works perfectly, thanks for your help !